# \protect on \rule in \caption does not work

Tags: captions

I would like to put a `\rule`command inside a caption. Classical solution is supposed to be `\protect{}` but that's not working. I still get `Error: Argument of \@caption has an extra }.` Why?

Here is a minimum example. (using MiKTeX 2.9 on XP)

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{\protect{ \rule{.6em}{.2ex} }}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\protect\rule`  not `\protect{`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\protect` does not take a `{}` argument: it must immediately precede the token it is protecting so

```
 \caption{\protect\rule{.6em}{.2ex}}
```